# Event handlers conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to slide down an up menu options. Everything goes fine until I click on the button again to slide the menu up, whereas it slides up and down again.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.login-btn, .lang-btn').on('click', function(event){
        var btn = $(this);
        $(document).on({
            mousedown: function(e) {
                btn.children('ul').slideUp();
            },
            scroll: function() {
                btn.children('ul').slideUp();
            }
        });
        btn.children('ul').slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();

    });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
.btn {
  margin:0 20px 0 0;
  background:#ddd;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.btn ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    display: none;
    height: 370px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#666;
    color:#fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="btn login-btn">
    Sign In
    <ul>
      <li>Some stuff here</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="btn lang-btn">
    English
    <ul>
      <li>English</li>
      <li>French</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there something wrong in my code?!

Comment: Can you just check after execution of the application how many times function of on click has been generates because two same functions can also be the problem, as in my case have the same problem I just checked it and remove the same function that comes twice and use only one from another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to do it was to add the ending `on` and `mousedown` event to stop propagation:

```
$('.login-btn, .lang-btn').on('click', function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.children('ul').slideToggle();
    btn.siblings().children('ul').slideUp();

    $(document).on("mousedown scroll", function(e) {
        btn.children('ul').slideUp();
    });
}).on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also thanks to **@DenysSéguret** for his great help.

Answer (score 2):

You're registering event handlers on every click and never unregister them, so on second time you open, you have two event handlers and both of them are called.

You could unregister them but there's a simpler way than to register and unregister : store the opened button:

```
(function(){
    var btn = null;
    $('.login-btn, .lang-btn').click(function(){
        if (btn) return;
        btn = $(this);
        btn.children('ul').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on("click scroll", function(){
      if (!btn) return;
      btn.children('ul').slideUp();
      btn = null;
      return false;
    });
})();
```

Side note: you might notice a few simplifications:

- no need to call `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`, just return `false`
- no need to repeat the event handler when binding, just specify several event types on binding

Comment: didn't help! the problem remains

Comment: Thank you for you edit, but it slides up and down again!

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat It seems the Denys answer works well! But, maybe you could add a snippet, people can help you easier by that

Comment: I edited with an different solution. But note that it also depends on what you really want (for example, when there's already an open div and you click on a closed one)

Comment: I added a snippet to my question. you can check your last jquery code on it. it really didn't work!

Answer (score -1):

your problem starts in here:

```
  $(document).on({
    mousedown: function(e) {
        btn.children('ul').slideUp();
    },
    scroll: function() {
        btn.children('ul').slideUp();
    }
});
btn.children('ul').slideToggle();
```

first you do a `slideUp` and then a `slideToggle` (which do `slideUp` or `slideDown` depends on the element situation).

so to fix your problem, remove either the `on` part or `slideToggle`! check this update on your snippet:

```js
        $(document).on({
            mousedown: function(e) {
                btn.children('ul').slideUp();
            },
            scroll: function() {
                btn.children('ul').slideUp();
            }
        });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
.btn {
  margin:0 20px 0 0;
  background:#ddd;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.btn ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    display: none;
    height: 370px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#666;
    color:#fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="btn login-btn">
    Sign In
    <ul>
      <li>Some stuff here</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="btn lang-btn">
    English
    <ul>
      <li>English</li>
      <li>French</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Using `slideToggle` I want to slide the menu up and down. Sliding the menu up on `mousedown` and window `scroll` has to be done. It can not be removed.

Comment: `slideToggle` changes the sliding depends on the situation! so if it's up it's gonna go down, and if it's down it's gonna go up! so in your `on` use `slideToggle` and remove `slideUp` and it's usage afterwards!

Comment: Did you try it? Seems if the `menu` is closed, scrolling would open it. Scroll will continually fire until you stop scrolling which will continually toggle.

Comment: check the snippet! I believe this is what u want!